# Node.js, how to keep server alive after a client exits?

Tags: node.js, tcp, p2p

I have a simple p2p app, but when I connect and exit as another peer or client the server stops completely. I've looked into `connection.setKeepAlive`, but it doesn't work they way I thought it would. I simply want the connection to any other peers to persist if another one exits.

```
const net = require('net')

const port = 3000
const host = 'localhost'

const server = net.createServer((connection) => {
    console.log('peer connected')
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening for peers')
})

const client = net.createConnection(port, host, () => {
    console.log('connected to peer')
})
```

Comment: Keepalive doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: When one peer disconnects that should not affect the connection to any other peer and nothing in the code you show would cause that.  So, it is not clear what problem you are actually trying to solve.  From a node.js point of view, the node.js process will stay alive as long as you have any open TCP connection or any listening server. So, as long as your server is still listening and alive, your node.js process will keep running (and not exit) no matter what happens with the client connections you have.  If you think you have an experience contrary to that, then we need more detail.

Comment: Well to test this I run this code and then a regular client from another script, it connects to it just fine but when I exit the client the node also stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script the port on which the server listen is the same that you use for the client connection, so the application is calling itself.

Here is a script that connect to its peer and disconnect every 2 seconds:

```
const net = require('net')

const myPort = 3001
const peerPort = 3002
const host = 'localhost'

const server = net.createServer((connection) => {
    console.log('peer connected')
})

server.listen(myPort, () => {
    console.log('listening for peers')
})


let connectionTest = function() {

    const client = net.createConnection(peerPort, host, () => {
        console.log('connected to peer')
    });
    client.on('close', (err) => {
        console.log("connection closed"); 
    });
    client.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log("error"); 
    });

    //TODO do stuff

    client.end();
    setTimeout(connectionTest, 2000);
}

setTimeout(connectionTest, 3000);
```

For every instance you should change the ports (myPort & peerPort)

Comment: Sorry that won't work, this is a p2p applicaiton and ever user needs to be a server and a client. I want the connections to persist, not exit after a task has been performed.

Comment: ops sorry, I missed the "p2p" part

Comment: Thanks, this could work well! I'll have to test it by adding some chat feature for the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `socket.on('error', (error) => {//...})` listener to treat a client connection drop.